Compreface Javascript SDK React App Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () After running command npm start
Currently running Compreface Javascript SDK webcam using IDE Visual Studio Code and running into an issue.
Once I run the command npm start I get the Chrome page to pop-up and start video. Once I click on start video I receive the following message when I open developer tools.
In the error it states:
"message" : "Missing header: x-api-key",
"code" : 20

Please also, see entire App.js coding and let me know where I am currently going wrong. Thank you all for your assistance!
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { CompreFace } from '@exadel/compreface-js-sdk';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const videoTag = useRef(null);
  const canvas1 = useRef(null);
  const canvas2 = useRef(null);
  const canvas3 = useRef(null);

  const drawFace = (canvasElement, faceData, extraCanvas) => {
    const evt = new Event("next_frame", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
    let box = faceData.result[0].box;

    canvasElement.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    extraCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);

    canvasElement.strokeStyle = 'green';
    extraCanvas.strokeStyle = "blue";
    extraCanvas.fillStyle = "white"

    extraCanvas.lineWidth = 5;
    canvasElement.lineWidth = 5;
    
    canvasElement.strokeRect(box.x_min, box.y_min, box.x_max - box.x_min, box.y_max - box.y_min);
    extraCanvas.fillText( Number.parseFloat(box.probability).toPrecision(5) + '  ' + faceData.result[0].gender.value + '  ' + faceData.result[0].age.low + '-' + faceData.result[0].age.high, box.x_min, box.y_min - 10)

  }
  
  const handleVideoStart = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true})
      .then(stream => videoTag.current.srcObject = stream)
      .catch( error => console.error(error) )

      videoTag.current.addEventListener('play', () => {
        // CompreFace init
        let server = "http://localhost";
        let port = 8000;
        let detection_key = "0548e3c5-fa91-4a82-aca4-4c6b56a69ffd";
  
        let core = new CompreFace(server, port);
        let detection_service = core.initFaceDetectionService(detection_key);
        // end of CompreFace init
  
        let ctx1 = canvas1.current.getContext('2d');
        let ctx2 = canvas2.current.getContext('2d');
        let ctx3 = canvas3.current.getContext("2d");

        document.addEventListener('next_frame', () => {
          ctx1.drawImage(videoTag.current, 0, 0, 640, 480)
          canvas1.current.toBlob( blob => {
            detection_service.detect(blob, {  limit: 1, face_plugins: 'age,gender' })
              .then(res => {
                drawFace(ctx2, res, ctx3)
              })
              .catch(error => console.log(error))
          }, 'image/jpeg', 0.95)
        })

        const evt = new Event("next_frame", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
              document.dispatchEvent(evt);
      })
  } 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <video ref={videoTag} width="640" height="480" autoPlay muted ></video>
        <canvas ref={canvas1} width="640" id="canvas" height="480" style={{ display: 'none' }}></canvas>
          <canvas ref={canvas2} width="640" id="canvas2" height="480" style={{ position: 'absolute' }} ></canvas>
        <canvas ref={canvas3} width="640" height="480" style={{ position: 'absolute' }}></canvas>

        <div>
          <button onClick={handleVideoStart} >Start video</button>
        </div>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I have followed all tutorial videos on installing and running Compreface on Github and have successful installed its software. It is just when I actually run the webcam program the camera is turned on but, I am not connected to Compreface on my local host. Also the green square grid does not populate because due to the fact it is not connected to my face collection on my Compreface Facial recognition app.

Is this question really about Java? At least the code seems like Javascript - are you aware that http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ ?

This code is Javascript. Do you have any possible solution to this problem? Thanks!
